# incenter of triangle help

Tags: calculus, geometry

A triangle has vertices (2,-2),(-2,2) and (0,6)need help finding incenter and Euler's line

This is a problem with many multiple parts like finding centroid, orthocenter, circumcenter. I have completed these parts, but do not know how to find the incenter or Euler's line. If someone could assist that would be great.

Comment: If you have found the centroid, orthocenter, and circumcenter can you verify that they lie on the same line?

Comment: oh I see, I could connect them together and find slopes for each. They should be equal and the equations should be too. That's how I find Euler's line right?

Comment: what about incenter?

Comment: Given that the coordinates make up an isosceles triangle we have this fact: The incenter of a triangle lies on its Euler line if and only if the triangle is isosceles. This fact requires a proof!

Comment: I'm wrong,the three points don't make up an isosceles triangle...

Answer (score 1):

As already [pointed out by Alan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522061/incenter-of-triangle-help#comment1116615_522061), having the centroid and orthocenter Euler's line may be constructed by that (see also [Euler Line @Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line)).

With the coordinates at hand 
the Cartesian coordinates of the incenter are given by

$$(x_I,y_I)=\left(\frac{ax_a+bx_b+cx_c}{a+b+c},\frac{ay_a+by_b+cy_c}{a+b+c}\right), $$
where $a$ is the length of the sides opposite to $(x_a,y_a)$. $b$ and $c$  accordingly (see [Incenter@Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Incenter.html) for more information).

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://tinyurl.com/kwumsyj) could also help you to provide the lengths of the sides...